# How to delete rows when conditions are met while going row by row

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a data frame with ['Guest'] and ['Status'] as columns. How can I loop through each row and delete any row that has a ['Guest'] that has starts with "test"?

I have tried putting them into a list but it brings the index along with it. Is there a way to drop the index while converting it to a list?

[image: df1]

Comment: df[~df['Guest'].str.startswith('Test')]`

Comment: Thank you that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is

```
df[~df['Guest'].str.startswith('Test')]
```

Thank you @Quang Hoang